# Checking header for token presence

Tags: javalite, activeweb

Is it possible to check header for available token and other OAuth values with ActiveWeb ? Are there any examples repos ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no example repos, but you can access and set headers in controllers and filters:

http://javalite.github.io/activeweb/snapshot/org/javalite/activeweb/HttpSupport.html#header-java.lang.String-

so:

```
header(String name,String value); // sets a header on response
headers();                        // gets all request headers
header(String name);              // returns a request header
```

Once you have a header, you can do whatever you need to.

All controllers have these methods out of the box. If you need to do this in a filter, you  would inherit this class:

http://javalite.github.io/activeweb/snapshot/org/javalite/activeweb/controller_filters/HttpSupportFilter.html

Comment: Thank you very much, really helpful. I also found an example of its use in [one](https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-secure)  of javalite repos.